Taking Inputs from STM32 Pın with Ardunio IDE
Hello everyone I am making STM32 Nucleo project in Arduino IDE. I used to use Arduino and I can easily take output from any pin however now I am using STM32 Nucleo-L073RZ and I can't take ant output. I want to make simple thing. When I pressed the button if conditions are satisfied my water pump have to be work in any speed I don't want to control fan speed.
This is my code block thanks. When I press button all things are worked except engine.
And there are many pins STM32 I can't find the correct one for engine
DATASHEET
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

#define LCD_RS PB8
#define LCD_EN PB9
#define LCD_D4 PA8
#define LCD_D5 PB10
#define LCD_D6 PB4
#define LCD_D7 PA10

#define trigPin PA9
#define echoPin PA7

#define buton1 PA9

#define motor PC4

LiquidCrystal lcd( LCD_RS, LCD_EN, LCD_D4, LCD_D5, LCD_D6, LCD_D7 );

long duration, distance;

void setup()
{
    lcd.begin( 16, 2 );
    lcd.print( "SENSORED WATER" );
    lcd.setCursor( 3, 1 );
    lcd.print( "DISPENSER" );
    delay( 2000 );
    lcd.clear();

    pinMode( buton1, INPUT );
    pinMode( motor, OUTPUT );

    Serial.begin( 9600 );
    pinMode( trigPin, OUTPUT );
    pinMode( echoPin, INPUT );
}

void mainFunction()
{
    Serial.print( "Button State: " );
    Serial.println( digitalRead( buton1 ) );
    lcd.print( "CHOOSE AMOUNT" );
    lcd.setCursor( 0, 1 );
    lcd.print( "TALL VENTI GRANDE" );

    if( digitalRead( buton1 ) == 1 )
    {
        if( distance <= 5 )
        {
            lcd.clear();
            lcd.print( "Filling started" );
            digitalWrite( motor, HIGH );
            delay( 5000 );
            digitalWrite( motor, LOW );
            lcd.clear();
        }
        else
        {
            lcd.clear();
            lcd.print( "BARDAK KOY LA!" );
            delay( 2000 );
            lcd.clear();
        }
    }
}

void loop()
{
    mainFunction();
}

When I press button engine needs to be start.

Try blinking with that input pin first (config it as output and output high-low-high-low). To make sure you configure the correct pin. Sometimes pin numbering in Arduino environment could be off.

What physical pin of which connector did you connect the motor control to?.  How have you connected it? (not directly I hope). How do you know there is no output? (the motor not moving is not necessarily indicative, you need to scope the pin directly).

Note that you are only polling the button at 2 second intervals - are you holding the button down for long enough? You should loose the delay if you want instant response.  Delays in a "big-loop" architecture as used by Arduino are a bad idea in any case.  Better to use a state machine and poll millis() to determine time triggers state changes.  Most Arduino examples are poorly designed in this respect.

Does your display work?  If so then clearly the "I can't take ant [sic] output" is untrue.  I suspect your motor driver hardware is simply not connected correctly.

The title refers to "inputs", the question refers to "output" - which is it?

Your hardware looks something like this I hope?  (from https://highvoltages.co/tutorial/arduino-tutorial/arduino-relay/).
